# Using Google Apps for client's email domain but getting my own email forwarding/alias for free to my Google Apps email

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, alias

I'm a freelance web designer and, being really impressed with Gmail and Google Apps in general, I want to recommend this to all my clients. (Say no to spam and weekend phone calls about setting up POP clients!)

My only problem is this: I have no problem with $5 a month for each of their accounts but I'd like to have my own email at their domain.

With Google Apps I have `buswell@mydomain.com`. For a client they will have `tom@tomsbusiness.com`. But I'd like to have `buswell@tomsbusiness.com` that forwards straight to my `buswell@mydomain.com` and I don't want to pay another $5 a month for this! (I'll be doing this for many clients so it would add up a lot.)

This is just for doing the basics first steps of SEO—submitting websites to Google, Google maps, Yell.com etc. It's just much easier if I have `buswell@tomsbusiness.com` for verification, and I don't want to ask the client to be forwarding me emails.

Also, I need to be able to send emails and reply with this `buswell@tomsbusiness.com`.

This is the only thing that's putting me off using Google Apps for everyone!

I think I can do this if I'm in charge of all their domains on Google Apps and turn all the `buswell@`s into aliases?

Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From [Mail routing and delivery: Guidelines and best practices - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650?hl=en)

## Routing examples and uses cases

Several mail routing and delivery scenarios are listed below. If a use case applies to you, click the link for detailed instructions.

### Default routing - Use split delivery to route unregistered Google Apps users to an on-premise mail server

> If you are migrating from a legacy mail server to Gmail, you can test your Google Apps configuration with a subset of users before registering all of your users. During this time, the [MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/answer.py?answer=33352) for your domain are pointing to Gmail; but, a portion of your users are unregistered with Google Apps and will continue using the on-premise mail server (for example, Microsoft Exchange).
>
> To configure such a phased roll-out of Google Apps using split delivery, configure your mail routing and delivery options as follows:
>
> - For registered Google Apps pilot users, deliver inbound mail to the Gmail inbox.
> - For users who are not yet registered with Google Apps, deliver inbound mail to the legacy email inbox.
>
> An incoming message is then delivered to either a Gmail inbox or a legacy system inbox, depending on the recipient.
>
> To set up split delivery as described above, use the **Default routing** setting in the Admin console.
>
> > Note: Default routing defines domain-wide mail routing settings, and applies only to inbound messages.
>
> Route unregistered Google Apps users to an on-premise mail server:
>
> 1. [Sign in](https://admin.google.com/) to the **Google Admin** console.
> 2. From the dashboard, go to **Apps > Google Apps > Gmail > [Advanced settings](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?hf=ServiceSettings/service=email&subtab=filters)**.
> 3. If you've not done so already, add a host, or route, for your on-premise server (see [Setting up mail hosts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/answer.py?answer=2614757)).
> 4. Click the **Default routing tab**.
> 5. Click **Add setting**.
> 6. Navigate to the Specify envelope recipients to match section, and from the drop-down list, click **All recipients**.
> 7. Navigate to the **If the envelope recipient matches the above, do the following** section, and from the drop-down list, click **Modify message**.
> 8. Check the **Change route** box. From the drop-down list, click the name for your on-premise server (for example, Exchange on-premise).
> 9. In the **Options** section, click the **Perform this action only on non-recognized addresses** option.
> 10. Click Save.
>
> For more details and instructions, see [Default routing setting](https://support.google.com/a/answer/answer.py?answer=2368153).